# HTML Image map vs. multiple div elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am implementing an Angular component which has many little areas where user can click.
I see 2 ways how to do it:

1. use background image and define map areas where user can click, add click handler on the image.
2. use div for each clickable part and attach the click handler to parent element (so I don't have many click handlers on each div). Use the CSS to style each div so it looks like the image in 1.

The problem with 1. is that when the image changes I have to change the map coordinates too.
The advantage here is that it should work without problem in many browsers.

The advantage of the 2. is that I can style the component as I need (so it can be smaller, bigger, different font, etc.), but it can have performance impact when I need to show more than one such component.

Which way would you choose and why? Or are there any other possibilities?

Edit:
forgot to mention that the component should also work on mobile devices

Comment: Either way, if the image changes you'll need to adjust coordinates. Maybe some of those can be easily calculated coordinates or coordinates that are actually handled in via CSS, but it really comes down to opinion and a judgement call based on your use case. For that reason I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't remember where but i just read a nice article about:

**div(webkit-transform)** vs **svg** vs **canvas**

**To make it simple:**

- 1-50 elements = **divs & images**
- 50-500 elements = **svg**
- 500 and more elements = **canvas**

this are here just to give you an idea ...then everything depends on every element and device.

---

**Canvas would be the best solution for everything.**

The problem on canvas is the click handler.You need to create a collision detection script.
(i used a canvas with a background image(worldmap),to show the dots in real time of the current users.).but it's not clickable... (there is a clickable legend under/over the map)

**SVG is prbably the best solution in your case**

like @mainguy said u can draw stuff and add eventHandlers (or one like on the parent element).and the performance is better than divs.

**DIVS**

Most of the time i use div sets with one eventhanlder. they are so easy to use and style.. but only squares or circles.. and if you start to style them you loose alot performance (box-shadow..).
If you don't style the divs you can use alot of them.Especially if you put the eventhandler on the parentNode.
that way you can handle 1000's of elements without problems.(but don't use `position:absolute`)

**Image Map**

Again ... if there are not too many elements this is prolly also a good solution.. the simplest ... (the simplest way to draw your simple shapes).As soon you have you static MAP values you can then transform your imagesize recalculation the map with the ratio.. so thats not a problem.

---

I would go for the image map if there are not to many elements.

else SVG.

Everything depends on how many elements you have.

---

> 1. is that when the image changes I have to change the map coordinates too

if you use divs you don't have to change coords?

** *Mobile devices support more than ie browsers.*

Comment: When i use divs i don't need the coords, because i don't need them. In JS handler i know which element triggered the click event.

Comment: yeah right... i was thinking you change x-y position of the divs... and if yes there is another problem... some years ago i stopped to add position absolute to the div (or all htmlelements). because that is a BIG performance losss...when you scroll or animate .

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with a SVG library which are fast, easy to style and suporrted by most browsers.

[D3.js](http://d3js.org/)
is available for Angular as directive. Have not worked with his one yet. But it seems to be very popular. Just look on their homepage for a WOW! effect.

[Raphaël JS](http://raphaeljs.com/)
Was used by me in many projects. It has the big advantage that it supports even old IEs (sic!).

Just make a search for Angular SVG and/or JS and you will find a lot of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing the exact requirements, my default choice would be 2.

There are drawbacks, such us inability to easily map non-rectangular areas. The advantages however are huge, including easy maintenance, possible responsiveness, more robust styling possibilities and more.

The sole amount of divs shouldn't cause any problems and I wouldn't worry about it.

There are cases in which I would look for different implementation, though.